# How to have handlers run sequentially in re-frame?

Tags: clojure, re-frame

Starting with these two handlers that take care of getting the current user information:

```
(re-frame/register-handler
  :got-user
  (fn [db [_ user]]
    (assoc db :user user)))

(re-frame/register-handler
  :get-user
  (fn [db [_]]
    (ajax/GET "/user" 
       {:handler #(re-frame/dispatch [:got-user %1])})
    db))
```

in one page, I want to display the list of friends, but the problem is that it depends on the user being fetched first:

```
(re-frame/register-handler
  :get-friends
  (fn [db [_]]
    (when (nil? (:user db))
      (re-frame/dispatch [:get-user]))
    ; Here's the problem, as I need to way for get-users and got-users to run.
    (ajax/GET (str "/users/" (get-in db [:user :id])) 
       {:handler #(re-frame/dispatch [:got-friends %1])})
    db))
```

How should I structure this code?

Comment: I just discovered about re-frame, but here is an idea: why not dispatch `[:get-user {:next :get-user-friends}]` with a kind of continuation-passing style, where `:next` is the event to dispatch when we got a user? the handler for `:got-user` would dispatch the next event. So `:get-friends` gets splitted in two parts: `:get-friends` (get the user if needed) and `:get-user-friends` (get friends for the known user).

Comment: @coredump yeah, I toyed with that, but continuations are hard to maintain and debug and passing a key-word-as-a-continuation is bound to not be enough in the future in my humble opinion.

Comment: I don't understand why it would be hard to maintain and debug. It seems to me that you are already using an event-driven approach with callbacks (handlers). IMHO chaining events blends nicely with the existing framework. If I understand correctly, you can pass arbitrary arguments to the handlers for your future needs, not just keywords. Cheers.

Comment: @coredump yes, an event driven system is already hard to debug, but there's not much we can do about it. Continuation passing style is hard to debug because it's hard to reason why things are happening. You are running code X and you don't have a traceback, you only now that a continuation for running code X came from *somewhere*. I worked with continuation web servers in Scheme and Common Lisp, they make things hard.

Comment: @coredump the other problem with it is that now a handler also implements continuations which are two different tasks. There's a lack of separation of concerns there. Imagine 10 handlers all implementing continuations, they could be implemented differently and some might work in some situation and some not. Of course, I could abstract away the continuation part with functions and macros but since that would essentially end up being a new way of defining handlers, I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing anything in re-frame itself before extending it.

Comment: After reading a little more the documentation, I think I'd try to use  [https://github.com/Day8/re-frame#subscribe](subscriptions) for your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[First, the documentation specifically warns against creating handlers with side-effects](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Effectful-Event-Handlers) (i.e. dispatching events from event handlers). Second, don't try to re-use event handlers, but refactor the re-usable parts into helper functions. Using [re-frame-http-fx](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-http-fx), I'd write something like this:

```
(reg-event-fx
  :get-friends
  [trim-v]
  (fn
    [{db :db} [_]]
    {:http-xhrio  (if (:user db)
                  {:method          :get
                  :uri             (str "/users/" (get-in db [:user :id])) 
                  :on-success      [:got-friends]
                  :on-failure      [:get-friends-load-failed]}

                  {:method          :get
                  :uri             "/user" 
                  :on-success      [:get-friends-for-user]
                  :on-failure      [:get-friends-user-load-failed]})
     :db         db}
    ))
```

:get-friends-for-user would then first store the retrieved user and start fetching the friends.

Comment: I realize I'm only two years late answering your question :) but since it didn't seem to have a good solution, I thought my answer might help others who end up seeing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Taking some inspiration from the [article about solving the CPU hog problem](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Solve-the-CPU-hog-problem) I made get-friends call itself while user is nil but to avoid sending many requests to the server, it also adds a flag about the user being requested:

```
(re-frame/register-handler
  :get-friends
  (fn [db [_ user-requested]]
    (if-let [user (:user db)]
      (ajax/GET (str "/users/" (get-in db [:user :id]))
                {:handler #(re-frame/dispatch [:got-friends %1])})
      (do
        (when (not user-requested)
          (re-frame/dispatch [:get-user]))
        (re-frame/dispatch [:get-friends true])))
    db))
```

It works, but in a local machine it manages to call itself 9 times or so until got-user sets the user. Not sure if this would be a problem or not and I'm open to other solutions if they exist.